# Dynamically Update Styling on Button Click, D3 Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Question:** How would I dynamically update the styling of a bar chart on button click in D3?

**The Problem:** I have three data sets that have positive and negative values. The initial visualization, using data set 1, has the correct styling (green for positive numbers, red for negative). However, when I update the data, the styling doesn't change to reflect the new data in data set 2 and 3.

**The Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>d3 Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        select {
            display: block;
        }

        .rect {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .rect--positive {
            fill: green;
        }

        .rect--negative {
            fill: red;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Add 2 buttons -->
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col1');">Data Set 1</button>
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col2');">Data Set 2</button>
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col3');">Data Set 3</button>

    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 500")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        // Initialize the X axis
        var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(0.2);

        var xAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

        // Initialize the Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0])

        var yAxis = svg.append("g")

        // A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
        function update(selectedVar) {

            // Pull and parse the Data
            d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JPichichero/test/main/data", function (data) {

                // Add X axis
                x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }))
                xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x))

                // Add Y axis
                y.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return +d[selectedVar] }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d[selectedVar] })]);
                yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y))

                // variable u: map data to existing bars
                var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)

                // update bars
                u
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", function (d) { return "rect rect--" + (d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "negative" : "positive") })
                    .merge(u)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(Math.max(0, d[selectedVar])); })
                    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.abs(y(d[selectedVar]) - y(0)); })
            })
        }

        // Initialize plot
        update('col1')

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've been trying to make the styling dynamically update on button click, so data set 2 and 3 would also have the appropriate bars styled green and red. The approach I took was to attach an event listener to refresh the styling, but haven't been able to make that work.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Change a class on the wrapper element and then deal with it in CSS?

Comment: @Dominik, I thought that was the initial solution, but if you check the class attributes for the green bars that are negative, they got assigned wrong. The user has the right idea with class assignments, just something wrong with checking if it is positive or negative

Comment: @J. Pic , I found the problem and I am working on a solution.

Comment: An upvote and or selecting as the answer would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the class indicating positive/negative coloring only when entering elements:

```
   u.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", function (d) { return "rect rect--" + (d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "negative" : "positive") })
    .merge...
```

Elements are only entered once and methods chained to an enter selection called only once per entered element. If the data is updated, you aren't re-evaluating if the class needs to be switched for any already existing bar (they have already been entered, they are in the update selection). Instead, merge the update and the enter, then set the class:

```
u.enter()
 .append("rect")
 .merge(u)
 .attr("class", function (d) { return "rect rect--" + (d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "negative" : "positive") })
 .transition()
 ...
```

Now,  whenever elements are entered or updated with new data, the color will also be (re-)set as needed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>d3 Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        select {
            display: block;
        }

        .rect {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .rect--positive {
            fill: green;
        }

        .rect--negative {
            fill: red;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Add 2 buttons -->
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col1');">Data Set 1</button>
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col2');">Data Set 2</button>
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col3');">Data Set 3</button>

    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 500")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        // Initialize the X axis
        var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(0.2);

        var xAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

        // Initialize the Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0])

        var yAxis = svg.append("g")

        // A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
        function update(selectedVar) {

            // Pull and parse the Data
            d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JPichichero/test/main/data", function (data) {

                // Add X axis
                x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }))
                xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x))

                // Add Y axis
                y.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return +d[selectedVar] }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d[selectedVar] })]);
                yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y))

                // variable u: map data to existing bars
                var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)

                // update bars
                u
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .merge(u)
                    .attr("class", function (d) { return "rect rect--" + (d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "negative" : "positive") })
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(Math.max(0, d[selectedVar])); })
                    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.abs(y(d[selectedVar]) - y(0)); })
            })
        }

        // Initialize plot
        update('col1')

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to transition the color, you can't use a class to set the fill: the transition will interpolate between "negative" and "positive", two strings, but you could interpolate between two css colors if you set the fill attribute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>d3 Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        select {
            display: block;
        }

        .rect {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .rect--positive {
            fill: green;
        }

        .rect--negative {
            fill: red;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Add 2 buttons -->
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col1');">Data Set 1</button>
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col2');">Data Set 2</button>
    <button class="dataOption" onclick="update('col3');">Data Set 3</button>

    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 500")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        // Initialize the X axis
        var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(0.2);

        var xAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

        // Initialize the Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0])

        var yAxis = svg.append("g")

        // A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
        function update(selectedVar) {

            // Pull and parse the Data
            d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JPichichero/test/main/data", function (data) {

                // Add X axis
                x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }))
                xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x))

                // Add Y axis
                y.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return +d[selectedVar] }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d[selectedVar] })]);
                yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y))

                // variable u: map data to existing bars
                var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)

                // update bars
                u
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "rect")
                    // Set fill on enter if you want to transition to the final color:
                    .attr("fill", "black")            
                    .merge(u)
                    .transition()
                    .attr("fill", function(d) {
                        return d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "red" : "green"                  
                    })                   
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(Math.max(0, d[selectedVar])); })
                    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.abs(y(d[selectedVar]) - y(0)); })
            })
        }

        // Initialize plot
        update('col1')

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Andrew, this was extremely helpful. You helped me understand the "why" behind it, too. Appreciate it!

Comment: The file no longer exists :/